# To talk about admission to a university

Tags: passive-voice

> I want to get admitted into Cambridge University.
>
> I want to get myself admitted into Cambridge University.

I can't get admitted there. Is the sentence grammatical or acceptable if I don't use myself?  This is my question. Which sentence is acceptable here?

Comment: I included your comment in your post (use the [edit] button to make clarifications). It might help to explain what you mean by “I can’t get admitted there”. Is that simply how you _feel_?

Comment: Thank you. I need explanation.

Comment: "I want to _be_ admitted..." would be more correct. You don't need to specify 'myself'.